# How to refresh table after everytime button click in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I want to show data in a table by clicking on a searching button. I am facing issue which is that if there is no data in between "Fromdate - Todate" , error is coming properly but now after this i enter correct fromdate and todate then nothing is displaying in table. I checked chrome console data is coming from backend but not displaying in table

```js
$('#paymentdetails').click(function() {

  var getData = basePath + 'Admin/GetPaymentsForDate/?FromDate=' + $(".datepickerInputFROM").val() + '&ToDate=' + $(".datepickerInputTO").val()
  if (($(".datepickerInputFROM").val() == "") && ($(".datepickerInputTO").val() == "")) {
    alertify.alert('Please select dates to proceed.')
    return false;
    //$('#financetbl').html('');
  } else if (($(".datepickerInputFROM").val() == "") || ($(".datepickerInputTO").val() == "")) {
    alertify.alert('Please select dates to proceed.')
    return false;
    //$('#financetbl').html('');
  }
  $.ajax({
    url: getData,
    async: true,
    success: function(response) {
      //  alert(response[0]);
      $('#financetbl').html('');
      // if (response.resultCourse != '' && response[0]!= 'null') {
      if (response.length > 0) {

        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          tr = '<tr>'
          tr += "<td>" + response[i].applicationNumber + "</td>";
          tr += "<td>" + response[i].applicantName + "</td>"

          tr += '</tr>'
          $('#financetbl tbody').append(tr);

        }
        inittable();
        console.log(response)

      } else {
        console.log(response)
        alertify.alert("Error : No Payments Details Found");
        //flush the table
        $('#financetbl').html('No Payments Details Found');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: clear the table before making another ajax call

Comment: @AkashAgrawal could you please help me with some working example / jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that when you execute:

```
$('#financetbl').html('');
```

Then tbody is gone you lose your selector for:

```
$('#financetbl tbody').append(tr);
```

I think the first line should be:

```
$('#financetbl tbody').empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
    $('#financetbl').html('No Payments Details Found');
```

to

```
    $('#financetbl').html('<tr><td colspan="2">No Payments Details Found</td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have excess if statements and need to properly manage the table when results returned are empty.  So let's put that in an empty table row.

No idea what `inittable();` does so you may have to fix this to account for that.

```
$('#paymentdetails').on('click', function() {
  if (($(".datepickerInputFROM").val() == "") || ($(".datepickerInputTO").val() == "")) {
    alertify.alert('Please select dates to proceed.')
    return false;
  }
  var getData = basePath + 'Admin/GetPaymentsForDate/?FromDate=' + $(".datepickerInputFROM").val() + '&ToDate=' + $(".datepickerInputTO").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: getData,
    async: true,
    success: function(response) {
      $('#financetbl').find('tbody').html('');
      if (response.length > 0) {
        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          tr = '<tr>'
          tr += "<td>" + response[i].applicationNumber + "</td>";
          tr += "<td>" + response[i].applicantName + "</td>"
          tr += '</tr>'
          $('#financetbl tbody').append(tr);
        }
        inittable();
        console.log(response);
      } else {
        console.log(response);
        alertify.alert("Error : No Payments Details Found");
        //flush the table
        $('#financetbl').find('tbody').html('<tr><td>No Payments Details Found</td></tr>');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: inittable(); by this i am creating some button to print table or exporting table as excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like **JSON.parse()**

```
var json = '{"applicationName":"XYZ","applicationNumber":1}',
obj = JSON.parse(json);

alert(obj.applicationName);
```

or

```
var json = '{"applicationName":"XYZ","applicationNumber":1}',
obj = JSON && JSON.parse(json) || $.parseJSON(json);
```